# IntelliJ HTTP client with GraphQL requests stored in multiple .http files

Tags: intellij-idea, graphql

I am using *IntelliJ 2022.3.1 (Ultimate Edition)*.

I have multiple `.http` files containing `GRAPHQL` requests, for convenience, those files are kept in a subfolder of resource folder in test package, in our Java application. Those requests are defined in multiple files, because for many of them the query is rather big and it was hard to navigate in a single file.

My goal is to make running these queries as easy as possible, to ease testing.

I have already added environment variables with some details, like hostname or token‚ which I set in the headers.
I have also defined live template to prepare request headers quickly, when adding new request.

What I would like to do in addition is:

- read query from a file
- run queries from all the files with one click

The first problem is:
When I have a `GRAPHQL` request in `.http` file, I can successfully trigger it. But when I save exactly the same query in a file and try to load it when triggering request, I get validation exceptions. Is this not possible?

For example, this request works fine:

```
GRAPHQL {{path}}
Authorization Bearer {{token}}
Content-Type: application/graphql

query {
    total {
        amount
        currency
    }
}
```

But after saving the same query in a file and loading it like below, it fails in the app:

```
GRAPHQL {{path}}
Authorization Bearer {{token}}
Content-Type: application/graphql

< ./query.graphql
```

with

> Error executing GraphQL request! graphql.kickstart.servlet.InvocationInputParseException: Request parsing failed at graphql.kickstart.servlet.HttpRequestHandlerImpl.parseInvocationInput(HttpRequestHandlerImpl.java:72)

After digging a little bit more, it seems to be a difference in how the request is delivered to the endpoint. It looks like when providing query in the body - the request is packed in JSON, when loading request from a file - the request is sent as is

See difference:

```
// This works
POST /my-graphql/graphql, payload={"query": "query {\n total {\n amount\n currency\n }\n}"}

// This fails
POST /my-graphql/graphql, payload=query { total { amount currency } }
```

Looks like IntelliJ bug?

The second issue is that when I right click on a folder to run all requests, IntelliJ gives me option to run all tests - which is not what I want. Is it possible to create run configuration to execute all `.http` requests from multiple files?

Comment: "I get validation exceptions" - could you provide a complete exception stack trace?

Comment: "Is it possible to create run configuration to execute all .http requests from multiple files?" - unfortunately, it is not yet supported. Feel free to upvote/comment for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-239323

Comment: @EgorKlepikov I edited my question to provide more information about the exception

Answer (score 0):

It looks like neither of above is possible now:

1. Loading query from a file: bug reported here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-310914/IntelliJ-Http-client-and-GraphQL-request-fails-when-loading-query-from-a-file
2. Triggering multiple .http files simultaneously - not possible, feature voting here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-239323